# Inaccessible content inside the scrollable box

Tags: html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, scroll

I am creating a login screen with bootstrap and jquery where the access card must be centralized.

The problem is that when the vertical scroll bar appears, scrolling to the top does not display all the content and the facebook button is inaccessible (depending on the height, google's too).

To compensate for the height of the navbar I tested the padding-top on the body and on the parent div, but without success.

I also tried adding a br with clearfix before the card and it didn't work.

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

html, body
{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body
{
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 3.5rem;
}

.btn-with-icon
{
  position: relative;
}
.btn-with-icon > div
{
  background-color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 0.15rem;
  height: 1.9rem;
  left: 0.17rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.17rem;
  width: 1.9rem;
}
.btn-with-icon > div > i
{
  height: 1.9rem !important;
  width: 1.9rem !important;;
}
.btn-with-icon > div > i::before
{
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  line-height: 1.9rem !important;
}
.btn-with-icon > div > .fa-facebook::before
{
  color: #3B5998;
}
.btn-with-icon > div > .fa-google::before
{
  color: #DB4437;
}
.btn-with-icon > span
{
  margin-left: 2rem;
}

.input-with-icon > i::before
{
  color: #C0C0C0;
  font-size: 1rem;
}
.input-with-icon > i
{
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
.input-with-icon > .form-control
{
  padding-left: 2rem;
}

.separator
{
  color: #C0C0C0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.horizontal-rule
{
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
.horizontal-rule::before,
.horizontal-rule::after
{
  background: #C0C0C0;
  content: '';
  flex: 1;
  width: 1px;
}
.horizontal-rule::before
{
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}
.horizontal-rule::after
{
  margin-top: 0.5em;
}

.vertical-rule
{
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}
.vertical-rule::before,
.vertical-rule::after
{
  background: #C0C0C0;
  content: '';
  flex: 1;
  height: 1px;
}
.vertical-rule::before
{
  margin-right: 0.5em;
}
.vertical-rule::after
{
  margin-left: 0.5em;
}

.small-text,
.small-text *
{
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
  <head>
    <title>test</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  </head>
  <body class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row h-100">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
        <span class="navbar-brand mb-0 h1">navbar</span>
      </nav>
      <div class="col-12 h-100 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center overflow-auto">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <form method="post" action="#">
              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-12">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block text-left btn-with-icon">
                    <div>
                      <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-fw"></i>
                    </div>
                    <span>Login with Facebook</span>
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-12">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block text-left btn-with-icon">
                    <div>
                      <i class="fa fa-google fa-fw"></i>
                    </div>
                    <span>Login with Google</span>
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-12 separator">
                  <span class="vertical-rule">OR</span>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-12 input-with-icon">
                  <i class="fa fa-at fa-fw"></i>
                  <input type="email" placeholder="e-mail" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-12 input-with-icon">
                  <i class="fa fa-lock fa-fw"></i>
                  <input type="password" placeholder="password" class="form-control">
                  <a href="#" class="float-right small-text">Forgotten password</a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-12">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block">
                    <span class="fa fa-check"></span>
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-12 text-center small-text">
                  <a href="#">Sign in</a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-6 mb-0 small-text">
                  <a href="#" target="_blank">Terms</a>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-6 mb-0 text-right small-text">
                  <a href="#" target="_blank">Privacy policy</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've removed align-items-center from the containing div and added m-auto to the card.

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

html, body
{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body
{
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 3.5rem;
}

.btn-with-icon
{
  position: relative;
}
.btn-with-icon > div
{
  background-color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 0.15rem;
  height: 1.9rem;
  left: 0.17rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.17rem;
  width: 1.9rem;
}
.btn-with-icon > div > i
{
  height: 1.9rem !important;
  width: 1.9rem !important;;
}
.btn-with-icon > div > i::before
{
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  line-height: 1.9rem !important;
}
.btn-with-icon > div > .fa-facebook::before
{
  color: #3B5998;
}
.btn-with-icon > div > .fa-google::before
{
  color: #DB4437;
}
.btn-with-icon > span
{
  margin-left: 2rem;
}

.input-with-icon > i::before
{
  color: #C0C0C0;
  font-size: 1rem;
}
.input-with-icon > i
{
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
.input-with-icon > .form-control
{
  padding-left: 2rem;
}

.separator
{
  color: #C0C0C0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.horizontal-rule
{
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
.horizontal-rule::before,
.horizontal-rule::after
{
  background: #C0C0C0;
  content: '';
  flex: 1;
  width: 1px;
}
.horizontal-rule::before
{
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}
.horizontal-rule::after
{
  margin-top: 0.5em;
}

.vertical-rule
{
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}
.vertical-rule::before,
.vertical-rule::after
{
  background: #C0C0C0;
  content: '';
  flex: 1;
  height: 1px;
}
.vertical-rule::before
{
  margin-right: 0.5em;
}
.vertical-rule::after
{
  margin-left: 0.5em;
}

.small-text,
.small-text *
{
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
  <head>
    <title>test</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  </head>
  <body class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row h-100">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
        <span class="navbar-brand mb-0 h1">navbar</span>
      </nav>
      <div class="col-12 h-100 d-flex justify-content-center overflow-auto">
        <div class="card m-auto">
          <div class="card-body">
            <form method="post" action="#">
              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-12">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block text-left btn-with-icon">
                    <div>
                      <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-fw"></i>
                    </div>
                    <span>Login with Facebook</span>
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-12">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block text-left btn-with-icon">
                    <div>
                      <i class="fa fa-google fa-fw"></i>
                    </div>
                    <span>Login with Google</span>
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-12 separator">
                  <span class="vertical-rule">OR</span>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-12 input-with-icon">
                  <i class="fa fa-at fa-fw"></i>
                  <input type="email" placeholder="e-mail" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-12 input-with-icon">
                  <i class="fa fa-lock fa-fw"></i>
                  <input type="password" placeholder="password" class="form-control">
                  <a href="#" class="float-right small-text">Forgotten password</a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-12">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block">
                    <span class="fa fa-check"></span>
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-12 text-center small-text">
                  <a href="#">Sign in</a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-6 mb-0 small-text">
                  <a href="#" target="_blank">Terms</a>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-6 mb-0 text-right small-text">
                  <a href="#" target="_blank">Privacy policy</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

For now i added a new Class to prevent the Card from expanding to much with a set max-height, Class in HTMl and the new CSS are marked with comments. I will try to look further into this and find out exactly why this happened but you can try this out and see if it fixes the issue on your page. In the Snippet it does.

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

html, body
{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body
{
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 3.5rem;
}

.btn-with-icon
{
  position: relative;
}
.btn-with-icon > div
{
  background-color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 0.15rem;
  height: 1.9rem;
  left: 0.17rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.17rem;
  width: 1.9rem;
}
.btn-with-icon > div > i
{
  height: 1.9rem !important;
  width: 1.9rem !important;;
}
.btn-with-icon > div > i::before
{
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  line-height: 1.9rem !important;
}
.btn-with-icon > div > .fa-facebook::before
{
  color: #3B5998;
}
.btn-with-icon > div > .fa-google::before
{
  color: #DB4437;
}
.btn-with-icon > span
{
  margin-left: 2rem;
}

.input-with-icon > i::before
{
  color: #C0C0C0;
  font-size: 1rem;
}
.input-with-icon > i
{
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
.input-with-icon > .form-control
{
  padding-left: 2rem;
}

.separator
{
  color: #C0C0C0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.horizontal-rule
{
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
.horizontal-rule::before,
.horizontal-rule::after
{
  background: #C0C0C0;
  content: '';
  flex: 1;
  width: 1px;
}
.horizontal-rule::before
{
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}
.horizontal-rule::after
{
  margin-top: 0.5em;
}

.vertical-rule
{
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}
.vertical-rule::before,
.vertical-rule::after
{
  background: #C0C0C0;
  content: '';
  flex: 1;
  height: 1px;
}
.vertical-rule::before
{
  margin-right: 0.5em;
}
.vertical-rule::after
{
  margin-left: 0.5em;
}

.small-text,
.small-text *
{
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  font-weight: 400;
}
/*This is the new CSS*/
.display-area{
  max-height: 80%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
  <head>
    <title>test</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  </head>
  <body class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row h-100">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
        <span class="navbar-brand mb-0 h1">navbar</span>
      </nav>
      <div class="col-12 h-100 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center overflow-auto">
      <!-- added a new class here -->
        <div class="card display-area">
          <div class="card-body">
            <form method="post" action="#">
              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-12">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block text-left btn-with-icon">
                    <div>
                      <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-fw"></i>
                    </div>
                    <span>Login with Facebook</span>
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-12">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block text-left btn-with-icon">
                    <div>
                      <i class="fa fa-google fa-fw"></i>
                    </div>
                    <span>Login with Google</span>
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-12 separator">
                  <span class="vertical-rule">OR</span>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-12 input-with-icon">
                  <i class="fa fa-at fa-fw"></i>
                  <input type="email" placeholder="e-mail" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-12 input-with-icon">
                  <i class="fa fa-lock fa-fw"></i>
                  <input type="password" placeholder="password" class="form-control">
                  <a href="#" class="float-right small-text">Forgotten password</a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-12">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block">
                    <span class="fa fa-check"></span>
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-12 text-center small-text">
                  <a href="#">Sign in</a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-6 mb-0 small-text">
                  <a href="#" target="_blank">Terms</a>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-6 mb-0 text-right small-text">
                  <a href="#" target="_blank">Privacy policy</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: check dantheman93's answer he found the Bootstrap-Mistake faster, his answer should solve it without adding any own CSS

Comment: Almost! The card is not maintaining the content ... but I appreciate the attempt. :)